# Array reducer syntax

Tags: arrays, reduce

Something is wrong with my array reducer syntax. I'm trying to add all odd numbers between 1 and n. I know that I need additional formatting but I can handle that. Suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Odd counter</title>
    <!-- This tool will add odd numbers between 1 and an input number.-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Input number N-->
    <input id="number" type="text"> <button onclick="oddAdder()">
        Add odds from 1
    </button>
    <p id="elements"></p>
    </br>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script>
        /* 
         * Check amount.
         */
        function oddAdder() {
            var sum = [];
            var reducer = function(accumulator, item); {
                return accumulator + item;
            }
            var total = sum.reduce(reducer)
            var target = document.getElementById("number").value;
            for (var i = 1; i <= target; i += 2) {
                sum.push(i)
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
            }
        }
        /* 
         * Display total
         */
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the semicolon in this line required? `var reducer = function(accumulator, item);{`

Comment: I believe so, according to some syntaxes that i have seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate `sum` before calling `sum.reduce` on it. Also, remove a stray semicolon from `var reducer = function(accumulator, item); {`.

After corrections, get the following code. I tested that it works.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Odd counter</title>
    <!-- This tool will add odd numbers between 1 and an input number.-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Input number N-->
    <input id="number" type="text"> <button onclick="oddAdder()">
        Add odds from 1
    </button>
    <p id="elements"></p>
    </br>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script>
        /* 
         * Check amount.
         */
        function oddAdder() {
            var sum = [];
            var reducer = function(accumulator, item) {
                return accumulator + item;
            }
            var target = document.getElementById("number").value;
            for (var i = 1; i <= target; i += 2) {
                sum.push(i)
            }
            var total = sum.reduce(reducer);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
        }
        /* 
         * Display total
         */
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wizard! Thanks for the syntax. Mucho appreciated!

Comment: Thank you. If this answer helped you, please mark the answer as the solution.